# Gridview sorting and paging. How to keep the paging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to sort and paging on my gridView.

I saw several post and I tried this :

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = sortExpression;
        switch (e.SortExpression)
        {
            case "Debit":
                if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
                    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
                    GridView1.DataSource = getItems().OrderByDescending(x => x.Debit);
                    GridView1.DataBind();                        
                    GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
                    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
                    GridView1.DataSource = getItems().OrderBy(x => x.Debit);
                    GridView1.DataBind();                        
                    GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

The sorting works well but the pagination disapears. I put the "AllowPaging" property to true after binding but I have all data on one page. Why?

Edit : If I remove "AllowPaging" or set to true before "Binding", I have an exception : An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: The data source does not support server-side data paging.

Comment: Why do you turn paging off and on? Can't you leave it on at all times?

Comment: I have a basic pagination for my grid and when I sort, I trurn off paging otherwise I have an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
   GridView1.AllowPaging = false;                       
   GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
```

May be the source of your issue.

In both the `IF`  & the `else` statement.

Comment: Surely if this needs to be added on both, then it doesn't need to be in either of them

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `GridView1.AllowPaging = true;` before `DataBind()`

Comment: I have an exception : An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The data source does not support server-side data paging.

Comment: What does getItems() return?

Comment: It's a method which recovers data following a "RadioButtonList" and "Checkbox". It's return an array of my personal Object (View_1).

Answer (score 0):

GridView by itself does not support sorting. This is done by the data source.
[Sorting Data in a GridView Web Server Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3cb265d3-9799-4091-bade-64ae7dbcad3c)

IQueryable (which inherits IEnumerable) will not page and sort when databound to GridView.

But you can convert IEnumerable collections to List instances with the `.ToList()` extension methods.

Changeing this:

```
 GridView1.DataSource = getItems().OrderByDescending(x => x.Debit);
```

to:

```
 GridView1.DataSource = getItems().OrderByDescending(x => x.Debit).ToList();
```

will allow the sorting and paging to work. (You may need to add the `Sorting` event)